# Is there a reason as to why my background image is repeating when I put it in production in Netlify but not in react itself?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, netlify

I have completed a project that has background images and when I'm in localhost the background image fits perfectly and does not repeat but when I try to add it to Netlify the website's background images does not fit perfectly and starts repeating.

crew CSS file:

```
.main-content-crew{
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('../../../images/crew/background-crew-desktop.jpg');
    width: 100vw;
}
```

the web page in localhost:
[localhost pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B4L3.jpg)

the netlify webpage:
[Netlify pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRboI.jpg)

home page CSS file:

```
.main-content-home{
    background: url('../../images/home/background-home-desktop.jpg');
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

Localhost pic:
[Localhost pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvdsK.jpg)

Netlify pic:
[Netlify pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynt6D.jpg)

Comment: Try to set an explicit `background-size` (cover, fit, percentage, whatever) and then set `background-repeat: no-repeat`. Could be an issue with interpretation on Netlify's end.